# Autocomplete jquery plugin does not work when data comes from database?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, autocomplete

I am using this plugin for textarea suggestion (auto completion). It is working fine as long as list is hardcoded. like this :-

> var suggests = ["Action", "ActionScript", "Borland"];

But I need words list from the database. When i get list from database, plugin does not respond. Here is what I am doing:-

Plugin I am using:-

> https://github.com/imankulov/asuggest/

Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var suggests = getList();
        var $txt = $('#<%=txtArea.ClientID %>');
        $txt.asuggest(suggests);
    });

function getList() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ajaxService.asmx/autocompletelist",
        data: "{groupUid:'" + 4 + "', clientUid: '" + 8 + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            return (data.d);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("No Match");
        }
    });
}
```

code behind:-

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> autocompletelist(int groupUid, int clientUid)
{
        //call to database for the list. 
          //code/

        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        result.Add("Action");
        result.Add("ActionScript");
        result.Add("Borland");
        return result;
}
```

Please suggest? Is it something to do with square brackets? How to get that in return from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ajax `success` function is executed asynchronously (it doesn't get fired until a response is received), but you're trying to use its result in a synchronous fashion. So when you call `$txt.asuggest(suggests);`, nothing happens because `suggests` has not been populated yet. This is because the ajax request hasn't finished, but your code doesn't know that. The simplest way to fix this is to put the logic for the UI in the `success` method itself. That way your plugin wont be called until the `suggests` variable is guaranteed to be populated. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getList();
});

function getList() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ajaxService.asmx/autocompletelist",
        data: "{groupUid:'" + 4 + "', clientUid: '" + 8 + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var $txt = $('#<%=txtArea.ClientID %>');
            $txt.asuggest(data);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("No Match");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: :) Thanks. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can first do it like this *alert(suggests)*，check whether the result was correct，then convert the result to array.
convert json to array:

```
var dataArray=eval(jsonStr);
for(var i in dataArray)
{
    //TODO
}
```